# How do you remove an element from an array of protocols in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, protocols, xcode6

Swift's protocol implementation is really driving me crazy right now. I have an array `observers` defined over a custom protocol `Observing` and I am trying to remove an element from that array given the element, but Swift is complaining that `Observing` doesn't implement `Identifiable` (which I think is actually another of my own protocols, unless there's also a system protocol called that). All I want to do is a reference comparison and remove the actual object. I don't care about performing any kind of comparison on the objects.

```
var observers = [Observing]()

func removeObserver( observer: Observing ) {
    for i in 0 ..< self.observers.count {
        if self.observers[i] == observer { // <='Observing' is not convertible to 'Identifiable'...?
            self.observers.removeAtIndex(i)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does the observer object have an override for the == compare aka allowing you to check if the objects are actually equal?

Comment: No it doesn't, but why should it need one? I just want to perform a reference equality comparison. Can objects not be compared in Swift?

Comment: For the reasons mentioned by ahruss. Definitely glad you found the answer you were looking for. In objective c there was a separation for == and isEquals... in swift there is no isEquals hence == is the equivalent of isEquals and === is for pointer comparison.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `==` operator checks for value-equality in Swift, and for there is no default implementation for it. What you want is reference equality, which you can get using `===` and `!==` in Swift.

See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_132) for more details.

> ## Identity Operators
>
> Because classes are reference types, it is possible for multiple constants and variables to refer to the same single instance of a class behind the scenes. (The same is not true for structures and enumerations, because they are always copied when they are assigned to a constant or variable, or passed to a function.)
>
> It can sometimes be useful to find out if two constants or variables refer to exactly the same instance of a class. To enable this, Swift provides two identity operators:
>
> Identical to (===)
>   Not identical to (!==)

Note that for the `===` operator to work, the objects must conform to the `AnyObject` protocol. You can guarantee this by suffixing the protocol with ": class", like this:

```
protocol SomeProtocol : class { ... }
```

Comment: Oh sweet, I had no idea Swift had a `===` operator (and yes I have read the book but must have skipped over that part).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I like `@class_protocol` better than `@objc` since I'm trying to stay pure Swift.

Comment: In beta5 it should be `protocol Name: class { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to compare if two Observing point to the same instance, use the === operator instead. This requires that the observer's must conform to AnyObject. An easy way to require Observing to only apply to AnyObjects would be to add the @class_protocol prefix to the protocol declaration.

Comment: Isn't `@class_protocol` the right way to do this, not @objc?

Comment: It looks like it would be. I wasn't aware of it. Thanks for the tip

Comment: `@class_protocol` prefix deprecated, new syntax: `protocol name: class {}`